# How can I obtain a new XenServer license using only the command line?

Tags: xen, xenserver

Many sites explain how to renew the license using XenCenter. Is there a way to do this directly from the console?

Answer (score 3):

The question is probably outdated, but just reference. From the [XenServer 6.1.0 Licensing FAQ](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134888):

> **Q: Can I apply a license without using XenCenter?**
>
> A: Yes, you can use the xe CLI. Run the host-apply-edition command.
>   For example, enter the following:

```
xe host-apply-edition edition=advanced|enterprise|platinum|enterprise-xd \ license-server-address=<license_server_address>host-uuid=<uuid_of_host> \ license-server-port=<license_server_port>
```

Answer (score 1):

For free edition you should get a new license each year from Citrix using this [web page](http://deliver.citrix.com/go/citrix/xenserver_activation). You will receive an email with the lic file.

On XenServer 6.1 and older versions you needed to copy (the lic it's a text file so you could open it, copy the text and create a new file on the dom0 and paste the text) the license file to the dom0 and add the license file using the command:

```
/opt/xensource/bin/xe host-license-add license-file=/root/license.xslic
```

On XenServer 6.2 and newer you need a Citrix License Server service ([free download here](https://www.citrix.es/downloads/licensing/license-server/license-server-version-11121-for-windows.html)) installed on a different machine, add the license file to the License Server and assign that server to the the XenServer using the command:

```
xe host-apply-edition edition=free|per-socket|xendesktop \ license-server-address=<license_server_address> host-uuid=<uuid_of_host> \ license-server-port=<license_server_port>
```

[Check here the FAQ](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX137838) about Licensing XenServer 6.2 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that an answer might reside [here](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1440017), in a post on the XenServer forums.

From the post, it appears that you need to do the following:

- Obtain the license file (I'm assuming you've already done this since you are asking how to renew the license)
- Place the file on a USB drive and plug it into the host machine
- Select "XenServer Details and Licensing" from xsconsole

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do not have a license file, I have a server with an expired license. All the computers on my network are linux-only and I'm trying to find a way not to install windows just to install XenCenter just to renew a a license .

Comment: Have you tried the xsconsole screen I mentioned to see if you can renew that way? I'm not right in front of it at the moment, but I think there might be a direct option there. I will look more as soon as I have the chance.

Comment: nope, xsconsole 5.6 does not have this option